# Eclipse 2022-12: folder with own snippets without creating new project

Tags: eclipse

I have a directory where I keep all my PHP snippets, common functions and classes and I was wondering how can I add that directory to the Project Explorer without creating a new project, so I can add/improve things as needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as my question wasn't answered and in Eclipse's documentation neither on internet searches get me to what I expected, the solution I found is creating a new project using my snippets/functions/classes folder.